# How does PCIe Endpoint device memory is mapped into the systems memory map (MMIO)?

Tags: memory-management, linux-device-driver, pci, pci-e, ioremap

How does **Linux Kernel** or **BIOS** map the **PCIe** **endpoint** device memory into systems **MMIO** space ? Is there any API to achieve it ?
Lets assume that when writing a Linux device driver for a PCIe endpoint device, How can we map **PCIe** device memory into MMIO space ? Or Is it true that the device is already mapped into MMIO by BIOS during enumeration and what I would need to do it just remap the device **MMIO** into the **kernel virtual addres**s space using **ioremap**() ?

Platform : Linux on x86

Comment: BIOS may or may not map PCIe device (they are supporting hotplug). In any case Linux OS has an algorithm to fo that.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this answer

**Role of the BIOS**

The BIOS (typically UEFI based) will do some sort of Depth-First Search (DFS) and enumerate all the children as PCIe is a self-enumerating bus. Since it has the view of the world (device, buses, processors) it will write an address to the BAR registers (could be BAR0 and or multiple of them). This will be the address the system will use and it will actually route these requests from the Host Agent (HA on x86/Intel platforms) to the Root Port to a PCIe switch all the way to the end point.

Each of these elements track what address ranges belong to themselves or one of their child devices (example a Switch may be the child of a Root Port)

**Role of the Device Driver**

The OS/Kernel will provide a toolkit of helper routines that the driver authors will use to access the device registers. Typically a driver may follow the folling routines

This is some sample driver pseudo-code, just to help illustrate the idea

> **1.** pci_resource_flags(pdev, 0) & IORESOURCE_MEM
>
> Check if a resource region is valid, here check for BAR 0
>
> **2.** pci_request_regions(pdev, "region")
>
> Take ownership of the resource/region
>
> **3.** drv->registers = pci_iomap(pdev, 0, SIZE_YOU_WANT_TO_MAP)
>
> This will give you kernel virtual address to device register mapping

*Note* : In case the BIOS does not enumerate, through Linux one can rescan the PCIe tree to see if a device can be seen or not.